# How to switch to another server if connection refused?

Tags: java, connection, telnet, switching

I need to switch to another if on current connection, connection refused, or if current IP do not exist. Here is a part of code:

```
String [] server= {"10.201.30.200", "10.66.20.70",}; // Servers array

public void Telnet(String[] server) {
    try {
        out2 = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
        String [] hrnc = {"HRNC01_", "HRNC02_", "HRNC03_","NRNC01_", "NRNC02_"};

        for (int i = 0; i < server.length; i++) {        
            // Connect to the specified server
            if (server[i].equals("10.201.30.200")) { 
                // Commands via telnet
            } else if (server[i].equals("10.66.20.70")) {
                // Commands
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

For example if first IP don't exist i need to connect to the next server.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  What I mean is, if you have tried something, how does it fail, what did you expect and what actually happened.

Comment: If i connect to the ip that do not exist i have an error - "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect" and my programm stop. I need to switch to another IP if current connection refused

Comment: So you have to stop your programming from stopping on that exception and make it continue instead. This is really not the place to be learning basic Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do the connection, capture exceptions and if it happen try another IP Address.

EDIT:
Of course! This is my implementation

```
package tests;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Connection {
    // Servers array
    private static final String[] server = { "10.201.30.200", "10.66.20.70" };
    // @logoff: default Telnet port
    private static final int port = 23;

    public static void telnet(String[] server) {
        PrintStream out2;
        try {

            out2 = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));

            String[] hrnc = { "HRNC01_", "HRNC02_", "HRNC03_", "NRNC01_",
                    "NRNC02_" };

            for (int i = 0; i < server.length; i++) {
                try {
                    // @logoff: try connection
                    Socket socket = new Socket(server[i], port);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // @logoff: typical "Connection timed out" or
                    // "Connection refused"
                    System.err.println("Error connecting to " + server[i]
                            + ". Error = " + e.getMessage());
                    // @logoff: continue to next for element
                    continue;
                }

                // Connect to the specified server
                if (server[i].equals("10.201.30.200")) {
                    // Commands via telnet
                }

                else if (server[i].equals("10.66.20.70")) {
                    // Commands
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // @logoff: your method returns void
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        telnet(server);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show on this example how can i do this? i'm not good in Java

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I'll more practice on it!

Comment: @Sam no problem. we are here to help anybody.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting each connection attempt in a try/catch statement